# XSD - complex content, base types, and same-named elements

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm having a weird issue. My company's application parses a lot of different structures, and generates schemas based on them. Actual XSD schemas are one of the many things we handle.

I'm working with a particular XSD schema that has a restriction that seems to override certain elements. Here is a sanitized version of that schema, with the exact structure in place:

```
<!-- Overriding Restriction -->
<xsd:complexType name="MyRestrictedChoice">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:restriction base="MyChoice">
             <xsd:choice>
                  <xsd:element name="Nothing" type="NothingType">
                       <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:documentation>My documentation</xsd:documentation>
                       </xsd:annotation>
                  </xsd:element>
                  <xsd:element name="Something" type="SomethingRestricted" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
             </xsd:choice>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>

<!-- Base Type -->
<xsd:complexType name="MyChoice">
    <xsd:choice>
        <xsd:element name="Nothing" type="NothingType">
             <xsd:annotation>
                  <xsd:documentation>My Documentation</xsd:documentation>
             </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="Something" type="SomethingOptional" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:choice>
</xsd:complexType>
```

The current behavior of our application is if you have a type that extends another type, the children of both types get combined and displayed in a result tree in our UI. That behavior seems to break down in this use case.

What I THINK the schema wants to do is have the Nothing & Something elements in the first block replace the Nothing & Something elements in the second. So there should only be one Nothing & one Something element in our tree in the UI. Currently, we're getting duplicates.

So: the reason I'm posting this here is to get clarification on XSD rules.

1. For a "restriction", is the expected behavior for the same-named elements to override the parent? Or is the expected behavior for them to co-exist?
2. For other forms of accessing a base type, is the expected behavior to override, or to co-exist?

Comment: Something type is different in each case, SomethingRestricted and SomethingOptional. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, when you define a complex type by restriction, everything in the new content model overrides everything in the old content model. Attributes are defined differently: with attributes, you define what's different in the restriction; but with child elements, you define the new (restricted) model, and the system has to go away and work out that the new model is consistent with (a valid restriction of) the old.